# Pack files into one, to later programmatically unpack them

Tags: c#, packaging

Is it possible to take all files and folders in a directory and pack them into a single package file, so that I may transfer this package over network and then unpack all files and folders from the package?

I tried looking into ZIP files with C#, because I'm aiming for the same idea, but the actual methods for it only comes with .NET 3.5 (I believe), I also want the program to be very lightweight, meaning I don't want external modules lying around that has to be taken with if I wish to unzip/unpack a single file.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need compression? Do you want to handle big files nicely?

Comment: @fejesjoco No, I really just want to find a way to put files in one package file. Exactly like ZIP, I don't really need compression.

Comment: Your demands seem unreasonable. You appear to want extra functionality without adding code or libraries.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You misunderstand. I don't mind adding code or libraries, but I'd prefer them to not be external or 2.5MB just to extract a ZIP file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a BinaryWriter/Reader and your own format. Something like this:

```
using (var fs = File.Create(...))
using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(...))
    {
        bw.Write(true); // means that a file will follow
        bw.Write(Path.GetFileName(file));
        var data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        bw.Write(data.Length);
        bw.Write(data);
    }
    bw.Write(false); // means end of file
}
```

So basically you write a bool that means whether there is a next file, the name and contents of each file, one after the other. Reading is the exact opposite. BinaryWriter/Reader take care of everything (it knows how long each string <strike>and byte array</strike> is, you will read back exactly what you wrote).

What this solution lacks: not an industry standard (but quite simple), doesn't store any additional metadata (you can add creation time, etc.), doesn't use a checksum (you can add an SHA1 hash after the contents), doesn't use compression (you said you don't need it), doesn't handle big files well (the problematic part is that it reads an entire file into a byte array and writes that, should work pretty well under 100 MB), doesn't handle multi-level directory hierarchies (can be added of course).

EDIT: The BinaryR/W know about string lengths, but not about byte array lengths. I added a length field before the byte array so that it can be read back exactly as it was written.

Comment: Now try to read this 'tarball'. Where does one file end and where does the next one start?

Comment: @CodeCaster: as I said, the BinaryReader will know where a string ends. I was mistaken about the byte array though, I will correct my answer.

Comment: Great answer! To people who want to write the reader:
Use BinaryReader and read exactly the same items in the same order.
E.g.: br.ReadBoolean(), br.ReadString(), br.ReadInt32()...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **ziplib**, it's free, open source and can be used in all .NET versions: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: I did take a look at this. The only issue with it is that it adds extra weight to my program. I'm really looking for something that just zips and unzips files... Thanks though!

Comment: There's also DotNetZip which is free and I think a bit simpler than SharpZipLib.  It's still going to add something extra to your app though.  There's not really any way around that unless you use what's already built into the .NET Framework though.  There has been ZIP support since .NET 3.0 but the Packaging implementation is a bit complex.  ZIP support in the Compression namespace is better but was only added in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Why should It add extra Wright. It's part of the .net Framework which youre Using already

Answer (score 1):

What i suggest you it's to consider the advantages taken by using an external library so you can forget a lot of troubles. A zip complex class could be a huge deal. Take a look at that: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ it's simple, stable and lightweigth.

By the way if you totally don'want external libraries and data compression isn't mandatory for your project you can manage it in a sort like this (please, consider it as a sample written in lees than an hour ;-) ):

usage:

```
//to pack
Packer.SimplePack sp = new Packer.SimplePack(@"c:\filename.pack");
sp.PackFolderContent(@"c:\yourfolder");
sp.Save();

//to unpack
Packer.SimplePack sp = new Packer.SimplePack(@"c:\filename.pack");
sp.Open();
```

Here is SimplePack:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Packer
{
    public class SimplePack
    {
        public class Header
        {
            public Int32 TotalEntries { get; set; }
            public Int64[] EntriesSize
            {
                get
                {
                    return EntriesSizeList.ToArray();
                }
            }
            private List<Int64> EntriesSizeList { get; set; }

            public Header()
            {
                TotalEntries = 0;
                EntriesSizeList = new List<Int64>();
            }

            public void AddEntrySize(Int64 newSize)
            {
                EntriesSizeList.Add(newSize);
            }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public Byte[] RawData { get; set; }
            public String Name { get; set; }
            public String RelativeUri { get; set; }

            public Int64 ItemSize
            {
                get
                {
                    Int64 retVal = 4; //Name.Lenght;
                    retVal += Name.Length;
                    retVal += 4; //RelativeUri.Length
                    retVal += RelativeUri.Length;
                    retVal += RawData.Length;

                    return retVal;
                }
            }

            public Byte[] SerializedData
            {
                get
                {
                    List<Byte> retVal = new List<Byte>();
                    retVal.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(Name.Length));
                    retVal.AddRange(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Name));
                    retVal.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(RelativeUri.Length));
                    retVal.AddRange(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(RelativeUri));
                    retVal.AddRange(RawData);
                    return retVal.ToArray();
                }
            }

            public Item()
            {
                RawData = new Byte[0];
                Name = String.Empty;
                RelativeUri = String.Empty;
            }
            public Item(Byte[] serializedItem)
            {
                Int32 cursor = 0;
                Int32 nl = BitConverter.ToInt32(serializedItem, cursor);
                cursor += 4;
                Name = Encoding.Default.GetString(serializedItem, cursor, nl);
                cursor += nl;
                Int32 rl = BitConverter.ToInt32(serializedItem, cursor);
                cursor += 4;
                RelativeUri = Encoding.Default.GetString(serializedItem, cursor, rl);
                cursor += rl;
                RawData = new Byte[serializedItem.Length - cursor];
                for (int i = cursor; i < serializedItem.Length; i++)
                {
                    RawData[i - cursor] = serializedItem[cursor];
                }
            }
        }

        public FileInfo PackedFile { get; private set; }
        public List<Item> Data { get; private set; }

        public Header FileHeaderDefinition { get; private set; }

        public SimplePack(String fileName)
        {
            PackedFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
            FileHeaderDefinition = new Header();
            Data = new List<Item>();
        }

        public Boolean PackFolderContent(String folderFullName)
        {
            Boolean retVal = false;

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderFullName);

            //Think about setting up strong checks and errors trapping

            if (di.Exists)
            {
                FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
                {
                    Item it = setItem(fi, di.FullName);
                    if (it != null)
                    {
                        Data.Add(it);
                        FileHeaderDefinition.TotalEntries++;
                        FileHeaderDefinition.AddEntrySize(it.ItemSize);
                    }
                }
            }
            //althoug it isn't checked
            retVal = true;

            return retVal;
        }

        private Item setItem(FileInfo sourceFile, String packedRoot)
        {
            if (sourceFile.Exists)
            {
                Item retVal = new Item();
                retVal.Name = sourceFile.Name;
                retVal.RelativeUri = sourceFile.FullName.Substring(packedRoot.Length).Replace("\\", "/");
                retVal.RawData = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile.FullName);
                return retVal;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            if (PackedFile.Exists)
            {
                PackedFile.Delete();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(PackedFile.FullName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //Writing Header
                //4 bytes
                fs.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(FileHeaderDefinition.TotalEntries), 0, 4);
                //8 bytes foreach size
                foreach (Int64 size in FileHeaderDefinition.EntriesSize)
                {
                    fs.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(size), 0, 8);
                }
                foreach (Item it in Data)
                {
                    fs.Write(it.SerializedData, 0, it.SerializedData.Length);
                }

                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            if (PackedFile.Exists)
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(PackedFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    Byte[] readBuffer = new Byte[4];
                    fs.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                    FileHeaderDefinition.TotalEntries = BitConverter.ToInt32(readBuffer, 0);
                    for (Int32 i = 0; i < FileHeaderDefinition.TotalEntries; i++)
                    {
                        readBuffer = new Byte[8];
                        fs.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                        FileHeaderDefinition.AddEntrySize(BitConverter.ToInt64(readBuffer, 0));
                    }

                    foreach (Int64 size in FileHeaderDefinition.EntriesSize)
                    {
                        readBuffer = new Byte[size];
                        fs.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                        Data.Add(new Item(readBuffer));
                    }

                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }




    }
}
```